# Simple chat client for Mac OS X which shows alerts and can be pinned to foregorund

Tags: osx, chat

I`m searching for a simple chat client for Mac OS X:

Requirements:

- It should be possible to pin the chat window to the foreground, so it is in front of alle other windows
- It should show those alerts on the screen if a new message arrived
- Login should be saved, so it is easy to start it every morning and keeping it up the whole day

Background:
In my company, we need a chat to check with less affort if somebody is available or talk about simple things like: "i`m ready with the task" without changing the room physically :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Slack](https://slack.com), it's a chat app for teams. 
The desktop app also [supports](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201355156-Desktop-notifications) notifications!

**Channels**

Organize your team conversations in open channels. Make a channel for a project, a topic, a team, or anything—everyone has a transparent view of all that’s going on.

**Private Channels**

For sensitive information, create private channels and invite a few team members. No one else can see or join your private channels.

**Direct Messages**

To reach a colleague directly, send them a Direct Message. It's completely private and secure.